# add values to rows and replicate it just below that value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add 150 to longitude and subtract 150 from latitude and paste them just below the their value.

```
OBJECTID     longitude     latitude
0            690187.1250  1870994.875
1            690202.1875  1870956.125
2            690213.0000  1870921.625
3            690223.8125  1871010.000
4            690245.3750  1870971.250
5            690262.6250  1871031.625
6            690286.3125  1870986.250
7            690297.1250  1871053.125
8            690327.3125  1871003.500
9            690331.6250  1871072.625
```

Expected output: just short example i want this for all the txt file

```
Index        longitude     latitude
0            690187.1250  1870994.875
0            690337.1250  1870844.875
1            690202.1875  1870956.125
1            690352.1875  1870806.125
```

This is what i have tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('F:\\pointcsv.txt', delimiter = ",")
def f1(d):
    dn = d.copy()
    for x in range(len(d)-2):
            idx = x + 0.5
            dn.loc[idx] = (d.iloc[x]['latitude'] - 150) and (d.iloc[x]['longitude'] - 150)       
    dn = dn.sort_index().reset_index(drop=False)
    return dn
nd = f1(df)
print(nd)
```

This is only working for longitude.how do i do it both at same time.Can someone help me fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `150` and `-150` to each column of `['longitude','latitude']` and concat + sort_index

```
out = (pd.concat((df[['longitude','latitude']],df[['longitude','latitude']]
         .add([150,-150]))).sort_index())
```

---

```
print(out)


     longitude     latitude
0  690187.1250  1870994.875
0  690337.1250  1870844.875
1  690202.1875  1870956.125
1  690352.1875  1870806.125
2  690213.0000  1870921.625
2  690363.0000  1870771.625
3  690223.8125  1871010.000
3  690373.8125  1870860.000
4  690245.3750  1870971.250
4  690395.3750  1870821.250
5  690262.6250  1871031.625
5  690412.6250  1870881.625
6  690286.3125  1870986.250
6  690436.3125  1870836.250
7  690447.1250  1870903.125
7  690297.1250  1871053.125
8  690477.3125  1870853.500
8  690327.3125  1871003.500
9  690331.6250  1871072.625
9  690481.6250  1870922.625
```

Comment: `.add([150,-150])` Cool one. Didnot think of that.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Anky already provided a cool answer. We can use *NumPy* functions here and leverage numpy's indexing. We can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) + [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html)

```
df = df.set_index('OBJECTID') # if it's not index already.
out = df.to_numpy()
out = np.repeat(out, 2, axis=0)
out[1::2, :]+=[150, -150]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index.repeat(2), columns=df.columns)

            longitude     latitude
OBJECTID                          
0         690187.1250  1870994.875
0         690337.1250  1870844.875
1         690202.1875  1870956.125
1         690352.1875  1870806.125
2         690213.0000  1870921.625
2         690363.0000  1870771.625
3         690223.8125  1871010.000
3         690373.8125  1870860.000
4         690245.3750  1870971.250
4         690395.3750  1870821.250
5         690262.6250  1871031.625
5         690412.6250  1870881.625
6         690286.3125  1870986.250
6         690436.3125  1870836.250
7         690297.1250  1871053.125
7         690447.1250  1870903.125
8         690327.3125  1871003.500
8         690477.3125  1870853.500
9         690331.6250  1871072.625
9         690481.6250  1870922.625
```

Timeit results:

Benchmarking setup:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1_000, 10_000, (100_000, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['longitude', 'latitude']) 
df.index.name = 'OBJECTID'
```

Results:

```
In [113]: %%timeit 
     ...: out = df.to_numpy() 
     ...: out = np.repeat(out, 2, axis=0) 
     ...: out[1::2, :]+=[150, -150] 
     ...: new_df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index.repeat(2), columns=df.column
     ...: s) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                       
2.57 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [114]: %%timeit 
     ...: (pd.concat((df[['longitude','latitude']],df[['longitude','latitude']] 
     ...:          .add([150,-150]))).sort_index()) 
     ...:                                                                       
32.3 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```